# White space is coming while switching from portrait to landscape in android mobile

Tags: android, html, css

I am trying with  **html 5** and **css 3** for creating mobile application where i tried with **1px** strip image repeat. I tested in mobile native browser.While  i change from portrait to landscape i found background flicker with a white background. 
I also tried CSS3 background gradient, it seems to be not render fully till the html page ends, this is the style i used in my css style sheet

```
body{
   background-image: url('../images/bg_strip.png');
   background-repeat: repeat;
   height: 100%;
   overflow:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure but i am trying tos give you a good answer hope it will work fine to you.

```
background: url(images/bg_strip.png) no-repeat center center fixed;
            -webkit-background-size: cover;
            -moz-background-size: cover;
            -o-background-size: cover;
            background-size: cover;
```